# Orienting a custom map in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, compass-geolocation

I need to do an application to navigate in a museum, using a map of the museum and Android's compass. The app should help the user go to some pre-set positions on the map.
Is it possible?
What should be the format of the map?

thanks

jul

Comment: Sounds like a fun project.  Have you considered using Android's Location Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the phone orientation by using the gyroscope and compass, it will however be a little harder to do the locations.

Because you will be indoors, chances are that your will not be able to get a fine location (GPS) because your phone will most probably not have a line of sight to a GPS satellite. This will mean your phone will have to rely on course location (network) which in terms of being accurate inside of a building is a bit of a stretch.

I did a project in University where I could pretty accurately track the location of a person inside of a building, but this was not based on the Android OS. If there are multiple wifi hotspots in the museum, wifi triangulation would probably be possible (I don't know if it is). To my knowledge, this would be the only way to accurately implement a project like this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. About the map orientation, what's the standard approach? Should I have an image with my map and know its orientation, then rotate it according to the compass' data?